# Comparing multiple columns in one row and change their value

Tags: r, dataframe, date, datetime

I cannot share the dataset but I will give an example, I have a dataset with 50 columns 48 of them are dates.

Here is an example of the data:

| Date1 | Date2 | Date3 | Date4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2014-02-12 01:12:21 | 2014-03-12 01:12:21 | 2014-04-12 01:12:21 | 2014-05-12 01:12:21 |
| 2014-05-12 01:12:21 | 2014-04-12 01:12:21 | 2014-01-12 01:12:21 | 2014-04-11 01:12:21 |

Here is what I want:

| Date1 | Date2 | Date3 | Date4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2014-02-12 01:12:21 | 2014-03-12 01:12:21 | NA | NA |
| NA | 2014-04-12 01:12:21 | 2014-01-12 01:12:21 | 2014-04-11 01:12:21 |

basically `Date2` column will be the determining column. If the other columns in that row are later than `Date2` column then, time of those columns will be `NA`.

Here is what I tried on my original dataset and what error I got(in this one I tried to replace dates with 1 and 0 based on the condition I specified):

```
ex <- Paidneed[ifelse(Paidneed[1:nrow(Paidneed),1] < Paidneed[1:nrow(Paidneed),3:50], 1,0),]
```

```
Error in ifelse(Paidneed[1:nrow(Paidneed), 5] < Paidneed[1:nrow(Paidneed),  : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In ifelse(Paidneed[1:nrow(Paidneed), 5] < Paidneed[1:nrow(Paidneed),  :
  Incompatible methods ("<.POSIXt", "Ops.data.frame") for "<"
2: In Paidneed[1:nrow(Paidneed), 5] < Paidneed[1:nrow(Paidneed), 3:50] :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example data set using `dput`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `base` solution:

```r
col <- grepl('Date', names(df))
df[col] <- lapply(df[col], \(x) replace(x, x > df$Date2, NA))
df
```

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(contains('Date'), ~ replace(.x, .x > Date2, NA)))
```

###### Output

```
#                 Date1               Date2               Date3               Date4
# 1 2014-02-12 01:12:21 2014-03-12 01:12:21                <NA>                <NA>
# 2                <NA> 2014-04-12 01:12:21 2014-01-12 01:12:21 2014-04-11 01:12:21
```

---

###### Data

```r
df <- read.csv(text = "Date1,Date2,Date3,Date4
2014-02-12 01:12:21,2014-03-12 01:12:21,2014-04-12 01:12:21,2014-05-12 01:12:21
2014-05-12 01:12:21,2014-04-12 01:12:21,2014-01-12 01:12:21,2014-04-11 01:12:21")
df[] <- lapply(df, as.POSIXct)
```